# Bootstrapping multiple different angluar2 views in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angular, systemjs

So I am building a chrome extension that has multiple html views, one for the browser action popup, and another for another feature(lets call them view1.html and view2.html).  I am using systemjs as my module loader. Because Chrome extensions do not allow inline JavaScript I can not include the below scripts in the html files, I instead must reference them from each of my html files:

systemjsInitView_.html:

```
 System.config({
 packages: {        
   scripts:{
     format: 'register',
     defaultExtension: 'js'
   }
 }
});

System.import('scripts/bootstrap-view_')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

bootstrap-view_.js:

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { PopupComponent } from './components/popup.component';

bootstrap(PopupComponent);
```

Here is my App folder structure

- view1.html
- view2.html
- scripts

  - systemjsInitView1.js
  - systemjsInitView2.js
  - bootstrap-view1.js
  - bootstrap-view2.js
  - components

    - more files...

I am wondering if I have multiple html views does this mean I need 2 versions of each of files above for each html page? (because I am loading different components into each page)?

I feel like this is bad coding style since these 2 files are more or less duplicated with minor changes, but I can't think of an easy remedy.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is here.

Comment: edited, please let me know if you understand now.